# Обособление оборота с "при"

Tags: пунктуация

Можно ли обособить оборот *"при сохранении текущей ситуации"* с двух сторон в данном предложении?

Безусловно, во многих проектах заложено импортное оборудование, и это вызывает некоторую рефлексию на рынке, но (запятая) при сохранении текущей ситуации, я думаю, что конъюнктура рынка претерпит значительные изменения и доля отечественного продукта будет расти.

Answer (score 1):

В примере, который Вы приводите, оборот при является обстоятельственным оборотом. В справочники Розенталя говорится: "Для смыслового выделения или для пояснения могут обособляться (выделяться запятыми) обстоятельства, выраженные существительными в формах косвенных падежей (обычно с предлогами), особенно если при этих существительных имеются пояснительные слова: **С приближением неприятеля к Москве, взгляд москвичей на своё положение не только не сделался серьёзнее, но, напротив, ещё легкомысленнее (Л. Т.) — в начале предложения смысловая нагрузка обособленного оборота усиливается в связи с тем, что к временному значению добавляется уступительное (‘взгляд москвичей становился легкомысленнее не только тогда, когда неприятель приближался к Москве, но и вопреки тому, что он приближался’);"**

Во многих случаях (в частности, в приведенном выше примере) **обособление или необособление обстоятельства зависит от степени распространенности оборота, его близости к основной части предложения, наличия добавочных оттенков значения, места по отношению к сказуемому, стилистической задачи и т. д., поэтому обособление *факультативно*.**

> На мой взгляд, здесь обособление не требуется.

Comment: _Серж: [в рассматриваемом примере] "оборот при является обстоятельственным оборотом"_. === С ним согласен. Интересно другое: от **какого** сказуемого Вы ставите вопрос к этому обстоятельству?

Comment: Конъюнктура потерпит изменения  -(когда?) - при сохранении текущей ситуации.

Comment: _Серж: Конъюнктура потерпит изменения -(когда?) - при сохранении текущей ситуации._ ===  Вопрос **от придаточного?** Удивлён тем, что ни Вы, ни Галина не видите ошибки в структуре предложенного Алёнкой предложения!

Comment: Слава, я про структуру ничего не говорил. Я лишь сказал, что это обстоятельственный оборот.

Answer (score 1):

> Безусловно, во многих проектах заложено импортное оборудование, и это
>   вызывает некоторую рефлексию на рынке, **но (запятая) при сохранении
>   текущей ситуации, я думаю, что конъюнктура рынка претерпит**
>   значительные изменения и доля отечественного продукта будет расти.

При такой конструкции предложения союз ***что*** — лишний.

Правильно:

***...но при сохранении текущей ситуации, думаю, конъюнктура рынка претерпит значительные изменения и доля отечественного продукта будет расти.***

Лучше, на мой взгляд, перестроить предложение:

***...но думаю, что при сохранении текущей ситуации конъюнктура рынка претерпит значительные изменения и доля отечественного продукта будет расти.***

Answer (score 0):

Можно. По правилу, приведённому Сержем.

То есть постановка запятой (обособление предложного оборота) факультативна, но если автор хочет - почему нет?

Есть такое правило редактора: не правь, если можно не править. Это проявление уважения к авторской интонации и его свободному волеизъявлению.

А вот союз *что* нам ни коим боком не указчик.

Comment: _Galina Avanesova: А вот союз что нам ни коим боком не указчик._ === _**"Блажен, кто верует..."**_